# Chrome extension: Watch for changes on an input box and trigger event based on whats inputted?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Problem - Watch for active input boxes in a page and trigger events if specific words are entered into the input box

**Steps**

1. Click 'reply or reply all'
2. Input box becomes active
3. Enter `|intro`
4. `|intro` text gets replaced with long form version. The `|intro` is like a snippet or short code

**Heres what I'm thinking**

1. Query all input boxes on a page
2. Check for input with focus
3. Add event listener on input to check for keyup events
4. Conditional statement to check if string contains specific snippet/short code
5. If condition is met then replace snippet with long form text

What do you think of my approach to this functonality

Comment: What's the significance of "reply or reply all"? Your approach seems reasonable, by the way.

Comment: Reply or reply all may be what triggers input box to open and become active. i just wanted to simulate the exact steps. I could really just query wherever the mouse cursor clicks no?

Comment: You could, but is there anything stopping you from just listening to every input the whole time?